# Control disappears behind parent window

Tags: c, drawing, win32gui

I am trying to create a program that has a main dialog and a child dialog; both modeless. The main dialog contains a tab control with two tabs titled "General" and "1 to 2", and three buttons. Here is a picture of the GUI;

[The main dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxz4i.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxz4i.jpg)

The child dialog contains a static control that is suppose to change when the user selects either tab. For the "General" tab, the static control should display "Tab0" and for the "1 to 2" tab the static control should display "Tab1".

The problem is, the static control disappears when a different tab is selected and it does not appear unless the main dialog is minimized and restored.

I tried handling the WM_PAINT message in the window procedure for the main dialog which fixed the disappearing static control but when the main dialog is minimized and restored, the controls for both dialog boxes disappear and only reappear when the window is moved.
When I let the system handle the WM_PAINT message, the first problem resurfaces.

I have also tried using the "RedrawWindow" function but that did not solve any of the problems.

Here is an explanation of the code;

The WinMain function creates the main window procedure, the main dialog template and contains the event loop. The main window is set to non-visible.

```
//The entry point function.
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, \
             HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, \
             PWSTR pCmdLine, \
             int nCmdShow){

 //Variable declarations
 INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX *tmpiccex = 0;
 HWND tmptbctrl;
 HWND mwindowhnd;
 DLGTEMPLATE *tmpdlgtemplate = 0;
 char *tmpstr = 0;
 WNDCLASSA winclass;
 MSG tmpmsg;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int tmpn2 = 0;
 unsigned int tmpn3 = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks

 //Initializations
 GLB_hInstance = hInstance;

 //Main logic

 //Allocate memory for one INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX.
 tmpiccex = (INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX*)calloc(1, sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX));

 //Set the members of the new tmpiccex
 //object.
 tmpiccex->dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
 tmpiccex->dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | \
             ICC_TAB_CLASSES;

 //Load the Common Controls DLL and register
 //some common controls.
 InitCommonControlsEx(tmpiccex);

 //Allocate memory to tmpstr.
 tmpstr = (char*)calloc(513, sizeof(char));

 //Initialize the window class.
 winclass.lpfnWndProc = WinProc1;
 winclass.hInstance = hInstance;
 winclass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(250,250,250));
 winclass.lpszClassName = "mwClass";
 winclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
 winclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
 winclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
 winclass.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_OWNDC | \
            CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
 winclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
 winclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
            
 //Register the window class.
 ret = RegisterClassA(&winclass);
 if(ret == 0){
  tmpn = GetLastError();
  sprintf(tmpstr, "Registering the window failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
  MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
         "Error", MB_OK);
  return TFAILED;
 }

 //Create the window.
 mwindowhnd = CreateWindowA("mwClass", \
                     "Experimenting with windows", \
                     WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | \
                 WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CAPTION | \
                 WS_SYSMENU, \
                     CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                 CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                 728, \
                 608, \
                     NULL, \
                     NULL, \
                     hInstance, \
                     NULL);
 if(mwindowhnd == NULL){
  tmpn = GetLastError();
  sprintf(tmpstr, "Creating the window failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
  MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
         "Error", MB_OK);
  return TFAILED;
 }

 //Set the GLB_HWndMain variable.
 GLB_HWndMain = mwindowhnd;

 //Create a dialog template for the
 //main dialog.
 ret = CreateDLGTemplate1(&tmpdlgtemplate);
 if(ret != TSUCCESS){
  sprintf(tmpstr, "CreateDLGTemplate1 failed.\nError: %d.", tmpn);
  MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
         "Error", MB_OK);
  return TFAILED;
 }

 //Create a modeless dialog box that
 //represents the main dialog.
 CreateDialogIndirectA(hInstance, \
              tmpdlgtemplate, \
              mwindowhnd, \
              DlgProc1);

 //Process window messages.
 while(TTRUE){
  
  //Wait for a message to enter the
  //queue.
  ret = GetMessage(&tmpmsg, \
         NULL, \
         0, \
         0);

  if(ret > 0){

   //Translate the message.
   TranslateMessage(&tmpmsg);

   //Dispatch the message by
   //calling the window pro-
   //cedure.
   DispatchMessage(&tmpmsg);

  }else{

   MessageBox(NULL, "Exiting.", \
          "Success", MB_OK);

   //Exit the while loop.
   break;

  } //EndIf

 } //End while loop.

 //Free variables

 //Returns
 return TSUCCESS;

}
```

The main window procedure handles messages sent to main window.

```
//Definition of the main window
//procedure.
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc1(HWND hwnd, \
                      UINT uMsg, \
                      WPARAM wParam, \
                      LPARAM lParam){

 //Variable declarations
 HWND hwindow = 0;
 HDC tmphdc = 0;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 unsigned int tmpmsg = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(hwnd == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 }

 //Initializations
 hwindow = hwnd;
 tmpmsg = uMsg;

 //Main logic

 //Process the window message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_DESTROY){

  //Place a quit message in the
  //queue.
  PostQuitMessage(0);

  //Return.
  return TSUCCESS;

 } //EndIf

 if(tmpmsg == WM_PAINT){

  //Start painting.
  tmphdc = BeginPaint(hwindow, &ps);

  //Finished painting.
  EndPaint(hwindow, &ps);

  //Returns
  return 0;

 } //EndIf

 ret = DefWindowProc(hwindow, \
               tmpmsg, \
               wParam, \
               lParam);

 //Free variables

 //Returns
 return ret;

}
```

The next function creates the dialog template for the main dialog. The main dialog only contains a tab control with two tabs.

```
//Creates the dialog template for
//the main dialog window.
TRESULT CreateDLGTemplate1(DLGTEMPLATE **outobj){

 //Variable declarations
 DLGTEMPLATE *tmpdlgtemplate = 0;
 DLGITEMTEMPLATE *tmpdlgitem = 0;
 wchar_t *tmpbuffer = 0;
 wchar_t *tmpwstr = 0;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int tmpn2 = 0;
 int tmpn3 = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(outobj == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 }

 //Initializations

 //Main logic

 //Allocate memory to tmpbuffer.
 //This will store the dialog
 //template and its items.
 tmpbuffer = (wchar_t*)calloc(4096, sizeof(wchar_t));

 //Start to initalize the dialog
 //template.

 //Set the tmpdlgtemplate pointer to
 //the beggining of the buffer.
 tmpdlgtemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)tmpbuffer;

 //Get the dialog box system base units.
 tmpn3 = GetDialogBaseUnits();

 //Initialize the tmpdlgtemplate.
 tmpdlgtemplate->style = WS_CAPTION | \
                 WS_SYSMENU | \
                 WS_MINIMIZEBOX | \
                 WS_OVERLAPPED | \
                 WS_VISIBLE | \
                 DS_CENTER;
 tmpdlgtemplate->dwExtendedStyle = 0;
 tmpdlgtemplate->cdit = 1;
 tmpdlgtemplate->x = ((CW_USEDEFAULT * 4) / \
                (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));
 tmpdlgtemplate->y = ((CW_USEDEFAULT * 8) / \
                (tmpn3 >> 16));
 tmpdlgtemplate->cx = ((728 * 4) / \
                 (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));;
 tmpdlgtemplate->cy = ((608 * 8) / \
                 (tmpn3 >> 16));;

 //Get the start of the subsequent
 //three arrays.
 tmpn = (sizeof(DLGTEMPLATE) / 2);

 //Set the dialog title to tmpwstr.
 tmpwstr = L"Experimenting with windows.";

 //Set the three arrays of 16-bit
 //elements that follow the dialog
 //template.
 tmpbuffer[tmpn] = 0; //The 16-bit menu.
 tmpbuffer[(tmpn + 1)] = 0; //The 16-bit window class.
 wcscpy((tmpbuffer + (tmpn + 2)), \
       tmpwstr); //The dialog title.

 //Calculate the start position of
 //the item dialog template.

 //Get the length of the dialog title.
 tmpn2 = wcslen(tmpwstr);

 //Add tmpn2, tmpn and the number 3.
 tmpn = (tmpn2 + tmpn + 3);

 //Align tmpn on a 32-bit boundary.
 if((tmpn % 2) > 0){

  //Add one to tmpn.
  tmpn = (tmpn + 1);

 } //EndIf

 //Set certain properties of the 
 //items in the dialog.

 //Get the dialog item template.
 tmpdlgitem = (DLGITEMTEMPLATE*)(tmpbuffer + tmpn);

 //Initialise the dialog item templates.

 //Start with the tab control.
 tmpdlgitem->style = WS_CHILD | \
               WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | \
               WS_VISIBLE;
 tmpdlgitem->dwExtendedStyle = 0;
 tmpdlgitem->x = ((32 * 4) / \
            (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));;
 tmpdlgitem->y = ((32 * 8) / \
            (tmpn3 >> 16));;
 tmpdlgitem->cx = ((680 * 4) / \
             (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));;;
 tmpdlgitem->cy = ((488 * 8) / \
             (tmpn3 >> 16));;;
 tmpdlgitem->id = 100;

 //Update the offset into the buffer.
 tmpn = (tmpn + (sizeof(DLGITEMTEMPLATE) / 2));

 //Set the arrays that follow each
 //dialog item template.

 //Set the window class.
 wcscpy((tmpbuffer + tmpn), \
       WC_TABCONTROLW); //The tab control.
 
 //Get the length of the window class.
 tmpn2 = wcslen(WC_TABCONTROLW);

 //Update the offset into the buffer.
 tmpn = (tmpn + tmpn2 + 1);
 
 //Set the window title.
 tmpbuffer[tmpn] = 0;

 //Update the offset into the buffer.
 tmpn = (tmpn + 1);

 //Set the creation data.
 tmpbuffer[tmpn] = 0;

 //Free variables

 //Returns
 *outobj = (DLGTEMPLATE*)tmpbuffer;
 return TSUCCESS;

}
```

The next function creates the dialog template for the child dialog. The child dialog only contains a static control that changes when a different tab is selected.

```
//Creates a dialog template for a
//child dialog.
TRESULT CreateDLGTemplate2(wchar_t *inwstr, \
                   DLGTEMPLATE **outobj){

 //Variable declarations
 DLGTEMPLATE *tmpdlgtemplate = 0;
 DLGITEMTEMPLATE *tmpdlgitem = 0;
 wchar_t *tmpbuffer = 0;
 wchar_t *tmpwstr = 0;
 wchar_t *tmpwstr2 = 0;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int tmpn2 = 0;
 int tmpn3 = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(outobj == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 }
 if(inwstr == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 }
 if(*inwstr == 0){
  return TSTRISEMPTY;
 }

 //Initializations
 tmpwstr2 = inwstr;

 //Main logic

 //Allocate memory to tmpbuffer.
 //This will store the dialog
 //template and its items.
 tmpbuffer = (wchar_t*)calloc(4096, sizeof(wchar_t));

 //Start to initalize the dialog
 //template.

 //Set the tmpdlgtemplate pointer to
 //the beggining of the buffer.
 tmpdlgtemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)tmpbuffer;

 //Get the dialog box system base units.
 tmpn3 = GetDialogBaseUnits();

 //Initialize the tmpdlgtemplate.
 tmpdlgtemplate->style = WS_CHILD | \
                 WS_OVERLAPPED | \
                 WS_VISIBLE;
 tmpdlgtemplate->dwExtendedStyle = 0;
 tmpdlgtemplate->cdit = 1;
 tmpdlgtemplate->x = ((100 * 4) / \
                (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));
 tmpdlgtemplate->y = ((100 * 8) / \
                (tmpn3 >> 16));
 tmpdlgtemplate->cx = ((250 * 4) / \
                 (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));;
 tmpdlgtemplate->cy = ((50 * 8) / \
                 (tmpn3 >> 16));;

 //Get the start of the subsequent
 //three arrays.
 tmpn = (sizeof(DLGTEMPLATE) / 2);

 //Set the three arrays of 16-bit
 //elements that follow the dialog
 //template.
 tmpbuffer[tmpn] = 0; //The 16-bit menu.
 tmpbuffer[(tmpn + 1)] = 0; //The 16-bit window class.
 tmpbuffer[(tmpn + 2)] = 0; //The window title.

 //Add tmpn and the number 3.
 tmpn = (tmpn + 3);

 //Align tmpn on a 32-bit boundary.
 if((tmpn % 2) > 0){

  //Add one to tmpn.
  tmpn = (tmpn + 1);

 } //EndIf

 //Initialise the dialog item templates.

 //Next initialize the static control.
 //This is another dialog template item
 //that follows the tab control in the
 //dialog template.

 //Get the dialog item template.
 tmpdlgitem = (DLGITEMTEMPLATE*)(tmpbuffer + tmpn);

 //Initialize the dialog item template.
 tmpdlgitem->style = WS_CHILD | \
               WS_VISIBLE | \
               SS_LEFT | \
               SS_SIMPLE;
 tmpdlgitem->dwExtendedStyle = 0;
 tmpdlgitem->x =((20 * 4) / \
             (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));;
 tmpdlgitem->y = ((20 * 8) / \
            (tmpn3 >> 16));;
 tmpdlgitem->cx = ((224 * 4) / \
             (tmpn3 & 0xFFFF));;;
 tmpdlgitem->cy = ((24 * 8) / \
             (tmpn3 >> 16));;;
 tmpdlgitem->id = 101;

 //Update the offset into the buffer.
 tmpn = (tmpn + (sizeof(DLGITEMTEMPLATE) / 2));

 //Set the arrays that follow each
 //dialog item template.

 //Set the window class.
 wcscpy((tmpbuffer + tmpn), \
       WC_STATICW); //The static control.
 
 //Get the length of the window class.
 tmpn2 = wcslen(WC_STATICW);

 //Update the offset into the buffer.
 tmpn = (tmpn + tmpn2 + 1);
 
 //Set the window text.
 wcscpy((tmpbuffer + tmpn), \
       tmpwstr2);

 //Get the length of the window text.
 tmpn2 = wcslen(tmpwstr2);

 //Update the offset into the buffer.
 tmpn = (tmpn + tmpn2 + 1);

 //Set the creation data.
 tmpbuffer[tmpn] = 0;

 //Free variables

 //Returns
 *outobj = (DLGTEMPLATE*)tmpbuffer;
 return TSUCCESS;

}
```

The next function is the window procedure for the child dialog. It handles the WM_INITDIALOG message.

```
//The child dialog procedure.
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgChildProc1(HWND hwnd, \
                         UINT uMsg, \
                         WPARAM wParam, \
                         LPARAM lParam){

 //Variable declarations
 HWND tmphndwindow = 0;
 WPARAM tmpwparam = 0;
 LPARAM tmplparam = 0;
 unsigned int tmpmsg = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks

 //Initializations
 tmphndwindow = hwnd;
 tmpmsg = uMsg;
 tmpwparam = wParam;
 tmplparam = lParam;

 //Main logic

 //Handle the WM_INITDIALOG message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_INITDIALOG){

  //Set the window handle of the
  //current child dialog.
  GLB_HWndChildDialog = tmphndwindow;

  //Return
  return TRUE;

 } //EndIf

 //Returns
 return FALSE;

}
```

Finally, the next function is the window procedure for the main dialog. It creates the tabs and three buttons and attempts to handle the WM_CLOSE, WM_INITDIALOG, WM_PAINT and TCN_SELCHANGE messages.

```
//The procedure for the parent dialog.
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc1(HWND hwnd, \
                      UINT uMsg, \
                      WPARAM wParam, \
                      LPARAM lParam){

 //Variable declarations
 TCITEMA *tmptab = 0;
 TCITEMA *tmptab2 = 0;
 NMHDR *tmpnmhdr = 0;
 DLGTEMPLATE *tmpdlgtemplate = 0;
 HWND hwindow = 0;
 HWND hwindow2 = 0;
 HWND tmpbtn = 0;
 HWND tmpbtn2 = 0;
 HWND tmpbtn3 = 0;
 HDC tmphdc = 0;
 HFONT tmpfont = 0;
 char *tmpstr = 0;
 LOGFONTA *tmplogfont = 0;
 PAINTSTRUCT ps;
 unsigned int tmpmsg = 0;
 int tmpn = 0;
 unsigned int tmpn2 = 0;
 int tmpn3 = 0;
 static int tmpn4 = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int ret = 0;

 //Argument checks

 //Initializations
 hwindow = hwnd;
 tmpmsg = uMsg;

 //Main logic

 //Allocate memory to tmpstr.
 tmpstr = (char*)calloc(513, sizeof(char));

 //Allocate memory to tmptab;
 tmptab = (TCITEMA*)calloc(1, sizeof(TCITEMA));

 //Allocate memory to tmptab2;
 tmptab2 = (TCITEMA*)calloc(1, sizeof(TCITEMA));

 //Allocate memory to tmplogfont.
 tmplogfont = (LOGFONTA*)calloc(1, sizeof(LOGFONTA));

 //Handle the WM_CLOSE message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_CLOSE){

  //Call the EndDialog function.
  EndDialog(hwindow, \
        TSUCCESS);

  //Place a quit message in the
  //queue.
  PostQuitMessage(0);

  //Return.
  return TRUE;

 } //EndIf

 //Handle the WM_INITDIALOG message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_INITDIALOG){

  //Set the global handle to the main
  //dialog window.
  GLB_HWndMainDialog = hwindow;

  //Get the window handle of the
  //tab control.
  hwindow2 = GetDlgItem(hwindow, \
                  100);
  if(hwindow2 == NULL){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "Could not find window.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Initialize the first tab.
  tmptab->mask = TCIF_TEXT;
  tmptab->dwState = 0;
  tmptab->dwStateMask = 0;
  tmptab->pszText = "   General      ";
  tmptab->cchTextMax = 16;
  tmptab->iImage = -1;
  tmptab->lParam = NULL;

  //Send the TCM_INSERTITEM message.
  ret = SendMessage(hwindow2, \
              TCM_INSERTITEM, \
              0, \
              tmptab);
  if(ret < 0){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "The SendMessage function failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Initialize the second tab.
  tmptab2->mask = TCIF_TEXT;
  tmptab2->dwState = 0;
  tmptab2->dwStateMask = 0;
  tmptab2->pszText = "   1 to 2       ";
  tmptab2->cchTextMax = 6;
  tmptab2->iImage = -1;
  tmptab2->lParam = NULL;

  //Send the TCM_INSERTITEM message.
  ret = SendMessage(hwindow2, \
              TCM_INSERTITEM, \
              1, \
              tmptab2);
  if(ret < 0){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "The SendMessage function failed.\nError: %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Create a child dialog template.
  ret = CreateDLGTemplate2(L"Tab0", \
                   &tmpdlgtemplate);
  if(ret != TSUCCESS){
   sprintf(tmpstr, "CreateDLGTemplate2 failed.\nError: %d.", ret);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Create a child dialog that is
  //modeless.
  CreateDialogIndirectA(GLB_hInstance, \
                  tmpdlgtemplate, \
                  GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                  DlgChildProc1);

  //Create an apply button.
  tmpbtn = CreateWindowA(WC_BUTTON, \
                     "Apply", \
                     WS_CHILD | \
                 WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | \
                 WS_VISIBLE | \
                 BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                     288, \
                 536, \
                 120, \
                 32, \
                     hwindow, \
                     NULL, \
                     GLB_hInstance, \
                     NULL);
  if(tmpbtn == NULL){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "Creating the apply button failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
   return TFAILED;
  }

  //Create a close button.
  tmpbtn2 = CreateWindowA(WC_BUTTON, \
                      "Close", \
                      WS_CHILD | \
                  WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | \
                  WS_VISIBLE | \
                  BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                      432, \
                  536, \
                  120, \
                  32, \
                      hwindow, \
                      NULL, \
                      GLB_hInstance, \
                      NULL);
  if(tmpbtn2 == NULL){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "Creating the close button failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
   return TFAILED;
  }

  //Create a close button.
  tmpbtn3 = CreateWindowA(WC_BUTTON, \
                      "Exit", \
                      WS_CHILD | \
                  WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | \
                  WS_VISIBLE | \
                  BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                      576, \
                  536, \
                  120, \
                  32, \
                      hwindow, \
                      NULL, \
                      GLB_hInstance, \
                      NULL);
  if(tmpbtn3 == NULL){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "Creating the exit button failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
   return TFAILED;
  }

  //Initialize the logical font.
  tmplogfont->lfHeight = 20;
  tmplogfont->lfWidth = 10;
  tmplogfont->lfEscapement = 0;
  tmplogfont->lfOrientation = 0;
  tmplogfont->lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
  tmplogfont->lfItalic = FALSE;
  tmplogfont->lfUnderline = FALSE;
  tmplogfont->lfStrikeOut = FALSE;
  tmplogfont->lfCharSet = ANSI_CHARSET;
  tmplogfont->lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS;
  tmplogfont->lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
  tmplogfont->lfQuality = ANTIALIASED_QUALITY;
  tmplogfont->lfPitchAndFamily = ((DEFAULT_PITCH & 0x03) | \
                        (FF_ROMAN << 4));
  strcpy(&(tmplogfont->lfFaceName[0]), \
       "Segoe UI");

  //Create a handle to a font.
  tmpfont = CreateFontIndirect(tmplogfont);

  //Send the WM_SETFONT message.
  ret = SendMessage(tmpbtn, \
              WM_SETFONT, \
              tmpfont, \
              FALSE);
  if(ret < 0){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "The SendMessage function failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Send the WM_SETFONT message.
  ret = SendMessage(tmpbtn2, \
              WM_SETFONT, \
              tmpfont, \
              FALSE);
  if(ret < 0){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "The SendMessage function failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Send the WM_SETFONT message.
  ret = SendMessage(tmpbtn3, \
              WM_SETFONT, \
              tmpfont, \
              FALSE);
  if(ret < 0){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "The SendMessage function failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Return
  return TRUE;

 }

 //An event handle for changes to 
 //the tab selected.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_NOTIFY){

  //Get the notification message header.
  tmpnmhdr = lParam;

  //Check if the pointer is not NULL.
  if(tmpnmhdr != NULL){

   //Get the notification code or number.
   tmpn2 = tmpnmhdr->code;

   //Check if the notification code is
   //TCN_SELCHANGE.
   if(tmpn2 == TCN_SELCHANGE){

    //Get the window handle of the
    //tab control.
    hwindow2 = GetDlgItem(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                    100);
    if(hwindow2 == NULL){
     sprintf(tmpstr, "Could not find the tab control.\nError: %d.", ret);
     MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
            "Error", MB_OK);
    }

    //Get the tab index of the selected 
    //tab.
    tmpn3 = SendMessage(hwindow2, \
                  TCM_GETCURSEL, \
                  0, \
                  0);

    //Destroy the current child dialog 
    //window.
    DestroyWindow(GLB_HWndChildDialog);

    //Get the correct dialog template
    //based on the tab index.

    //Compare the index to zero.
    if(tmpn3 == 0){

     //Get a dialog template for the
     //first tab.
     ret = CreateDLGTemplate2(L"Tab0", &tmpdlgtemplate);
     if(ret != TSUCCESS){
    sprintf(tmpstr, "The CreateDLGTemplate2 function failed.\nError: %d.", ret);
    MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
             "Error", MB_OK);
     } //EndIf

    }else{

     //Compare the index to one.
     if(tmpn3 == 1){

    //Get a dialog template for the
    //second tab.
    ret = CreateDLGTemplate2(L"Tab1", &tmpdlgtemplate);
    if(ret != TSUCCESS){
     sprintf(tmpstr, "The CreateDLGTemplate2 function failed.\nError: %d.", ret);
     MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
              "Error", MB_OK);
    } //EndIf

     } //EndIf
    } //EndIf

    //Create a new modeless dialog box.
    CreateDialogIndirectA(GLB_hInstance, \
                 tmpdlgtemplate, \
                 GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                 DlgChildProc1);

    //Return
    return TRUE;

   } //EndIf
  } //EndIf
 } //EndIf

 //Handle the WM_PAINT message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_PAINT){

  return TRUE;

 }

 //Free variables

 //Returns
 return FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I simply handled the WM_PAINT message in the child dialog window procedure where I set the text of the static control using the WM_SETTEXT message.

```
 //Handle the WM_PAINT message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_PAINT){

  //Set the text of the static
  //control.

  //Get the window handle of the
  //static control.
  tmphndwindow2 = GetDlgItem(GLB_HWndChildDialog, \
                       101);
  if(tmphndwindow2 == NULL){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "Could not find window.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Send the WM_SETTEXT message.
  ret = SendMessage(tmphndwindow2, \
              WM_SETTEXT, \
              0, \
              GLB_StaticCtrlText);
  if(ret < 0){
   tmpn = GetLastError();
   sprintf(tmpstr, "The SendMessage function failed.\nLast error returned %d.", tmpn);
   MessageBox(NULL, tmpstr, \
          "Error", MB_OK);
  }

  //Free variables
  free(tmpstr);

  //Return
  return TRUE;

 }
```

Now the program works as expected and the static control is updated each time a different tab is selected.

Comment: This only worked for static controls. After adding an edit control, the problem happened again. So what I did was place the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style to each window and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Now the controls are disappearing whenever the window client area is off-screen and then returns on-screen. So what I did was handle the WM_PAINT message in the two dialogs' window procedure where I called the RedrawWindow function. That problem is fixed but that introduced another problem similar to before where the controls are disappearing when the main dialog is minimized and then maximized. If you have any suggestions please reply.

Comment: I finally got the results I was looking for. There seems to be two drawing stages, one that is done by the system and the other done manually. I simply had to understand both to get the results expected. The windows developer website on Win32 was extremely helpful.